# how to get information of music files from assets folders?

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

I have following code which reads my phone and gets information of the music files in my phone

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
String[] projectionSongs = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projectionSongs,
                    selection, null, null);
```

Now I want to same information from assets folder itself.
I am trying

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///assets/");
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projectionSongs,
                    selection, null, null);
```

But it is not working. There is no information in cursor. However I have some mp3 files in assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void playBeep() {
    try {
        if (m.isPlaying()) {
            m.stop();
            m.release();
            m = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("your_audio_file_name.mp3");
        m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
        descriptor.close();

        m.prepare();
        m.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        m.setLooping(true);
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help u. Thank you